# Heroku is giving me a 503 when trying to open my web app, Yet it works fine on my local host

Tags: node.js, heroku

these were the recent logs from  my CLI using `heroku logs --tail`

```
    2020-11-15T10:18:43.902773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-15T10:18:43.946803+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-15T10:19:16.927207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=damp-castle-73586.herokuapp.com request_id=f2dc9c35-875e-4a01-97ca-b468fa10b2c6 fwd="197.210.76.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-15T10:19:17.711408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damp-castle-73586.herokuapp.com request_id=dae1b2f6-e951-4d26-98ab-ab26a9925b76 fwd="197.210.53.175" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please any help would be appreciated.
Here is what my Procfile lools like:

```
{
  "name": "mern_shopping_list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shoppping list built with the MERN stack",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "Pofi Abel",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more logs, as it can only be seen that app is getting crashed, nothing else is shown here

Comment: Can you share your Procfile

Comment: I wish could provide more logs, but that's exactly all the logs return sadly :(   @MohitGupta

Comment: I just added the Procfile up, Thanks @svikramjeet